# Expected value of strictly convex function is strictly convex?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have one question that I am confused about. 
X is random variable with finite mean, $\alpha$ $\in$ (0,1) and $\phi_{1}$,$\phi_{2}$ are strictly convex functions. Then I know that for each t the function $g(t,x) = \alpha \phi_{1}((t-x)_{+}) + (1-\alpha) \phi_{2}((t-x)_{-})$ is strictly convex in x. It should follow that $E[g(X,x)]$ is strictly convex in x. (Reason for this is that it implies that its minimizer is unique) I don't understand why it follows that $E[g(X,x)]$ is strictly convex in x ? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $t \mapsto a(t), t \mapsto b(t)$ are integrable and
$a(t) < b(t)$ ae. Then $E a < E b$.

Fix $x \neq y$ and $\lambda \in (0,1)$, then

$g(t, \lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) < \lambda g(t,x) + (1-\lambda) g(t,y)$
for all $t$.

Hence $E [g(X, \lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)] < E[\lambda g(X,x) + (1-\lambda) g(X,y) ] = \lambda E[ g(X,x)] +(1-\lambda) E [g(X,y) ]$.

**Addendum**: If $f(t) >0$ for ae. $t$, then $Ef > 0$. To see this, let $A_n = \{ t | f(t) > {1 \over n} \}$, then there is some $n$ such that $\mu A_n >0$ and $Ef \ge {1\over n} \mu A_n >0$.

Comment: Would you be so kind and explain me more the first implication:   Suppose $t \mapsto a(t), t \mapsto b(t)$ are integrable and
$a(t) < b(t)$. Then $E a < E b$.

Comment: @MatusD.: I added a note at the end. Let $f=b-a$.